# Toggle between green and red and there will be counter to count number of times toggle is pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hi i am creating a project but not sure how to use the useEffect, the toggle button will toggle between green and red and the same time there is a counter will keep track the number of toggle is pressed and also is there a way to use toggle without using the boolean. thanks

```
function App() {
  const [isToggled, setToggled] = useState(true);
  const [counterState, setCounterState] = useState(0);
  
  const toggleGreenRed = () => setToggled(isToggled ? 'Green' : 'Red' );
  const incrementCounter = () => setCounterState(counterState + 1);
  
  useEffect(() => {}); 

  return (
    <div>

      <button onClick={toggleGreenRed}>Toggle status</button>
      <h1>{isToggled}</h1>
      <h3>{counterState}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Your isToggled,setToggled should be a boolean

Comment: ok sure.. btw you know how to apply the useEffect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way of doing it, without using a `useEffect hook`.

Here, you can see the example without using `useEffect` hook.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [isToggled, setToggled] = useState(true);
  const [counterState, setCounterState] = useState(0);

  const toggleGreenRed = () => {
    setToggled(!isToggled);
    setCounterState(counterState + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleGreenRed}>Toggle status</button>
      <h1>{isToggled ? "Green" : "Red"}</h1>
      <h3>{counterState}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In here, what I've done so far is: increase the counter on the same time, whenever you press the button.

But if you wants to try with `useEffect` here is the code:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [isToggled, setToggled] = useState(true);
  const [counterState, setCounterState] = useState(-1);

  const toggleGreenRed = () => setToggled(!isToggled);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCounterState(counterState + 1);
  }, [isToggled]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleGreenRed}>Toggle status</button>
      <h1>{isToggled ? "Green" : "Red"}</h1>
      <h3>{counterState}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In here, you can see, `useEffect` has `isToggled` dependency. Which means, whenever the `isToggled` value change, the `useEffect` run and increase the value of counter.

You can learn more about `useEffect` hook from [react official doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: Start initial state from -1 or else the initial render will give counter value as 1 instead of 0

Comment: Yes this is true, because `useEffect` run once at first by default.